# Memory leak in jQuery AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, setinterval

I've written a little chat-box widget which runs an ajax call every second, to fetch new messages that have been posted. The problem is it's leaking memory, and after only about 15 mins of being open it crashes my browser (Firefox).

It's probably me, as I am a relative newbie, and I'm sure I've missed something out or am not unsetting my variables, etc..

```
var chat = {}
chat.fetchMessages = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/chat_ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { method: 'fetch'},
        success : function(data) {
            $('#chat .messages').html(data);
            $("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    });
}
chat.interval = setInterval(chat.fetchMessages, 1000);
chat.fetchMessages();
```

Can someone please glance at my (basic) code, and see if you can spot where the memory leak is occuring, and what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to unset some variables or something?

Many thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery? If you include jQuery 1.9.1, does it still occur? Older versions of jQuery had an internal cache where simple html strings were stored, then when developers used code such as yours above, it generated what appeared to be a memory leak because the cache is never cleared.

Comment: what I did not understand is $('#chat .messages').html(data); do you always get the whole chat content with AJAX request. I think you should request only the part user did not read yet append this to .messages. otherwise the data will be a huge text eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Never* use `setInterval()` with ajax, otherwise your requests never stay synchronized. Use `setTimeout()` instead and then pending your logic, initiate the `setTimeout()` recursively in the `complete` callback.

Example.

```
$(DoMyAjax); // start your ajax on DOM ready
function DoMyAjax() {
   $.ajax({ 
      complete: function() {
          // your logic here
          setTimeout(DoMyAjax, 1000);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: This actually multiplies the memory leaks - now it's megabytes per second instead of kilobytes!

Comment: @NeilHillman is this the case as Helga states? It seems like it would based on one of the above comment that says jQuery keeps a cache of html strings that never clears itself