# JavaScript clean memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management

I have a problem about memory management. 
My simpliest code is here:

```
var url="/abrapo.php";
var ob={start_:100, token:null}

function post_token(){
  $.post(url,{access:ob.token})
   .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      ob=data;
    });
}
```

I call function post_token every seconds. So after 2000 call user has problem of memory, ram goes up to 2GB.  I don't need to save anything just want to log data after post and clear memory. I've already googled and find delete ob. But  it does not clean the memory. What increase memory and how can I clean it without reloading the page

Comment: probably not a javascript issue, you should look at the php side of things instead

Comment: Why php? Memory problem has users not server,  this js makes problem

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/memory-leaks-with-ajax-calls

Comment: @Davitikakhiani ah sorry, you're right, probably the way you're setting the intervals then. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414094/memory-leak-in-jquery-ajax-calls

Comment: There isn't any presice solution

Comment: off course, to many requests will lead to the memory's problem, so maybe  the application will be crashed.I think isn't a js pronlem.Your request is complished by the network layer of the browser.

Comment: as @clodal has mentioned, maybe it is in your interval ... your requests might be taking too long and are getting backed up perhaps? are you using `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2):

Use your browser's profiling tools to determine where you're accumulating memory. In Chrome these profiling tools are located under the **Performance** tab in the Chrome Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>.

- Click the **Memory** checkbox near the top to enable memory profiling
- Click **Start Profiling and Reload Page** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
- Let the profiling run for a while, most pages load in 2-3 seconds but it sounds like your page needs to run longer than that
- Click the **Stop** button to halt the profiling

Among all the other performance graphs, you should see one for memory usage that looks something like this.

[image]

You can use this to see if, and when, the browser is performing garbage collections on the Javascript heap. You may need to manually clear certain objects by setting them to `null`. Also, try to avoid cyclical references and other complex referencing patterns that could cause the javascript engine to hold on to objects longer than it has to.

[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), for more about the memory management and garbage collection in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems while writing UI for a data acquisition device and managed to make it fly by setting every variable containing large data arrays to null whenever not used.

Your use case isn't easy to replicate with just your code, but I suggest you try setting

```
data = null;
```

and

```
ob = null;
```

whenever not in use.

You might have to tweak suggestion a bit, say by assigning only token:

```
ob.token = data.token;
```

in such case only token would have to be set to null

```
ob.token = null;
```

What this achieves essentially is that it gives garbage collector a chance to clear unused objects since variables using those were clearly set to null. Oh, yes, and memory profiling is your friend to find out what exactly should you null

Answer (score 0):

According to your code example,  the problem is with console.log(data)
it make your  object  accessible  from Console. The Garbage collection will free memory only when the object  is no more accessible.

Comment: While it's true that, if the developer console is open, objects tend to stick around longer, they will eventually be garbage collected if the console is not open. That said, it would be likely be better to $.extend the ob object first and log it second.