# AJAX - refreshing page crashes Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery script which is refreshing a table on my website. It looks like that script is taking off all my memory after some time (checked on Firefox) - it depends how strong is my PC. How can I solve this or is it even possible ?

Here's code:

```
var url_one = './url_one';
var url_two = './url_two';
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        timeout: 3000,
        async: true
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#firstTable").load(url_one);
        $("#secondTable").load(url_two);
    }, (60000));
});
```

EDIT:
I've checked there is a warning in browser Console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help
>   http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

I can't find solution - mostly ppl say that async:false make that error but I've async: true;

Comment: what are you expecting that `$.ajax` function to do?

Comment: i do not see why the current code will use the memory until and unless there is something more in the load function of the first table and second table. You have to share the load table function and size of the data..

Comment: Well, I'm refreshing table on my website. I call URL and put it into table every 60 sec.

Answer (score 0):

it depends if problem is that memory keeps old results, or if number of calls increases and you retrieve multiple results at once.

i think you should check count of performed calls, lets say by printing into console each time function starts, and make sure they dont multiply.

you also could take a look at:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

or this ansver:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414094/memory-leak-in-jquery-ajax-calls)

*`setInterval()` vs `setTimeout()`